# Powershell/WKHTMLTOPDF : Can´t put variables into the "Input-Path"

Tags: variables, powershell, input, path, wkhtmltopdf

I have the following Problem:

I want to write a script which i Need for my Company.
 we have some reports of the Monitoring of our customers
 I Need to test the creationtime of a specified path. If the specified path is newer than the actually date +(-5 days), the script should convert that html in that path into the pdf.

Here is the script....

```
#PDFConverter

param([String] $pfad,[int] $monat,$new?)

$monat = Get-Date -Format MM
 $path = "\sv-fs01\usAG-Data\Kunden\ATEC\Reporting\IntelliPool\" + $monat + "\index.htm"
 $new? = Test-Path $path -NewerThan (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)

function get-pdf ($new,$monat,$path)

 {

if ($new? -eq "true")
 {

# wkhtmltopdf.exe doesn´t allow, that i use variables in the "input-path".

C:\test\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe "\sv-fs01\usAG-Data\Kunden\ATEC\Reporting\IntelliPool\" + $monat + "\index.htm"C:\test\Report.pdf

Write-Host "Pdf konvertiert und abgespeichert"

 }
 else
 {
 Write-Host "Report ist nicht neu, es wurde KEINE PDf erstellt." 

} 

}
```

Is it possible to use variables in the path (C:\test\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe "\sv-fs01\usAG-Data\Kunden\ATEC\Reporting\IntelliPool\" + $monat + "\index.htm"C:\test\Report.pdf)

Thanks 4 help!

enter code here

Answer (score 0):

You could build the strings first then execute wktmltopdf

```
$HTML =  "\\sv-fs01\usAG-Data\Kunden\ATEC\Reporting\IntelliPool\" + $monat + "\index.htm"
$PDF = "C:\test\Report.PDF"
& "C:\test\wkhtmltopdf.exe"  $HTML $PDF
```

Comment: i tried that a few times but it still doesn´t work ..:(
i think that wkhtmltopdf want the normal path without any variables in the Input path, but that is really important for me, without that variable is the script useless. ....-.-

Comment: if you replace the & with write-host whats returned ? Or whats returned if you try below script ?

$Monat = "Hamster"
$HTML =  "\\sv-fs01\usAG-Data\Kunden\ATEC\Reporting\IntelliPool\" + $monat + "\index.htm"
$PDF = "C:\test\Report.PDF"
Write-Host "C:\test\wkhtmltopdf.exe"  $HTML $PDF
C:\test\wkhtmltopdf.exe \\sv-fs01\usAG-Data\Kunden\ATEC\Reporting\IntelliPool\Hamster\index.htm C:\test\Report.PDF